# How do I calculate how much sugar to add, for carbonation

Tags: carbonation, priming, sugar

I have a brew, that I will need to bottle soon.
But, how do I calculate, how much sugar to add, before bottling?
I'll be adding table-sugar, but I am very worried about exploding bottles.

Are there some rules for calculating? I assume the type of beer you're making, also plays in. In my case, it's german wheat beer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule of thumb to go by - 1oz sugar per 1gal Beer. That will get you a nice carbonation on most beers. I typically just add 5oz every batch and don't mess with any calculations unless I'm intentionally under-carbonating a stout or something.

Answer (score 4):

Priming sugar amount depends on carbonation level, that is

```
Total carbonation = CO2 already in beer + CO2 from priming sugar
```

- CO2 already in beer depends on the temperature you bottle at
- CO2 from priming sugar is proportional to amount of sugar used
- Total carbonation is expressed in volumes (Vol) and depends on beer style.

You can find all this taken care of in online calculator, such as [this](http://www.brewersfriend.com/beer-priming-calculator/).

I experienced once a bottle bombing with a wheat beer (I used something like 4Vol ,taht is around 10-12g/l of sugar I guess). It was less dangerous than I thougt, but still potentially dangerous :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great online carbonation calculator : 
http://hbd.org/cgi-bin/recipator/recipator/carbonation.html
just type in the desired amount of Co2 and hey presto!

Hope this help you as much as it does for me.